# Fill each shape with selected pictures from folder and crop them to fill - VBA - Powerpoint or Word

Tags: vba, image, powerpoint, shapes, fill

With PowerPoint, I have created several templates made of groups of shapes that I would copy to create nice image galleries in a Word document.

[image]

My idea is to automate the following process:

1. select a shape
2. shape format > shape fill > picture > from a file
3. picture format > crop > fill

by a macro that would do:

1. select all shapes in the selected slide
2. chose a folder and select pictures
3. fill each shape with the pictures
4. crop all the pictures in the shapes to fill the shapes

I have a macro that fill a specific shape on a specific slide with an image thanks to the filedialog. Thanks to commandbars I can do the PictureFillCrop.

```
Sub FillPictureAndFillCrop()
Dim strFilePath As String
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
        If .Show <> 0 Then
            strFilePath = .SelectedItems(1)
            With ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(1).Fill
                .Visible = msoTrue
                .UserPicture strFilePath
            End With
            ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(1).Select
            CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("PictureFillCrop")
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

I still need to extend this macro to all the shapes of the selected slide with each pictures I have selected.
I have a previous macro with which I can select multiple pictures and add one picture per newly created slide.
I would like to adapt it to the macro above.

```
Sub AddOneImagePerNewSlide()
    Dim ImgI As Long, tmpDIAPO As Slide
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
        .Filters.Add "Images", "*.png, *.gif; *.jpg; *.jpeg", 1
        If .Show = -1 Then
            For ImgI = 1 To .SelectedItems.Count
                Set tmpDIAPO = ActivePresentation.Slides.Add(Index:=ImgI, Layout:=ppLayoutBlank)
                tmpDIAPO.Shapes.AddPicture FileName:=.SelectedItems.Item(ImgI), _
                    LinkToFile:=msoFalse, _
                    SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, _
                    Left:=0, Top:=0, _
                    Width:=-1, Height:=-1
            Next
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

I think it would be a mix of the 2 above macro would work.
Is it doable?

Comment: Your approach does not leverage the capabilities already built into PowerPoint. As a simpler route, create a custom layout that has **Picture Placeholders** in your preferred arrangement. Then fill those placeholders with pictures. They will automatically get cropped to maintain the original photo layout.

Comment: My only issue with Picture Placeholders is that you can't group them so it's more difficult to have a nice alignment with precise space between them. But still I could manage to do it. The main idea is to avoid to add picture one by one. On a document with more then 100 pictures if i could instead select them by group of 4 to 8 it would be way faster.

Comment: Grouping is completely unconnected with precise arrangement.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is doable.

With this macro you will not need to select the Shapes.

```
Sub ShapePictureFitCrop(Shape As Shape)
    Dim Width As Double, Height As Double
    
    With Shape
        Width = .Width
        Height = .Height
        .ScaleWidth 1, msoFalse
        .ScaleHeight 1, msoFalse
        .PictureFormat.CropRight = .Width * Width / 100
        .PictureFormat.CropBottom = .Height * Height / 100
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: How do you run it? I added it to a module but Powerpoint doesn't recognize it as a macro?

Comment: @Clemleb you would need to pass the shape to it from another macro.

Comment: Sorry I am not sure to understand this. On my side I have found how to select a picture and fill a shape but I need to loop it to all the shapes on the slide with several pictures.

Comment: @Clemleb You still have a lot to workout. You are better off posting specific problems as you can across them.

Answer (score 0):

@Clemleb

To loop through all the shapes on each slide, you'd do something like this:

```
    Option Explicit
    
    Sub EachShape()
    
    Dim oSh As Shape
    Dim oSl As Slide
    
    For Each oSl In ActivePresentation.Slides
    For Each oSh In oSl.Shapes
        ' You might add code here to
        ' ensure that it's the right shape type
        ' For example, exclude shapes with text
        If oSh.HasTextFrame And oSh.TextFrame.HasText Then
            ' Leave it alone
        Else
            Call DoSomethingWith(oSh)
        End If
    Next    ' Shape
    Next    ' Slide
    
    End Sub
    
    Sub DoSomethingWith(oSh As Shape)
        ' you could call TinMan's example here
        ShapePictureFitCrop (oSh)
        ' then do other things with the shape
    End Sub

Sub ShapePictureFitCrop(Shape As Shape)
    Dim Width As Double, Height As Double
    
    With Shape
        Width = .Width
        Height = .Height
        .ScaleWidth 1, msoFalse
        .ScaleHeight 1, msoFalse
        .PictureFormat.CropRight = .Width * Width / 100
        .PictureFormat.CropBottom = .Height * Height / 100
    End With
End Sub
```